# addClass on all matches attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three containers that contain a attribute. I want to add a class for all matches element on a parent that have common attributes. If I click on any of the  from sidebar, main content area or header class must be add on all matching attributes. (Something like trigger all three attributes on single click).

Below is the code:

```
<ul class='main-nav'>
    <li><a link-tab="lt-department" href=""> Departments </a></li>
</ul>    
<ul class='content tab-container'>
    <li><a link-tab="lt-department" href=""> Departments </a></li>
</ul>    
<ul class='sidebar'>
    <li><a link-tab="lt-department" href=""> Departments </a></li>
</ul>
```

```
var linkTab = $('li a[link-tab]'); 
$(linkTab).on('click', function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault(); 
     $(linkTab).parent('li').addClass('active'); 
});
```

Please help , how can I achieve this.

Comment: var linkTab = $('li a[link-tab]');    
$(linkTab).on('click', function(e){    
e.preventDefault();    
$(linkTab).parent('li').addClass('active');    
});

Comment: Inside the event handler, use `this` instead of `linktab`. Check the jQuery tutorial on event handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("a[link-tab]").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var attributeName = $(this).attr("link-tab");
    var matchedLinks = $("a[link-tab=" + attributeName + "]");

    matchedLinks.parent("li").addClass("active");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/37bGV/

The idea is to look for all the anchors that have the same **link-tab** value, in your case *lt-department*. Then, add the **.active** class to their **li** parents.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please, give me one +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this if you want functionality like trigger all three tag on single click :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var linkTab = $('li a[link-tab]'); 
   $(linkTab).on('click', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var attrName   = $(this).attr("link-tab");
        var matchLinks = $("a[link-tab=" + attributeName + "]");

        matchLinks.parent("li").addClass("active");
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I've already tried this. Problem is $(this) added class only current tag not all of three. I want some functionality like trigger all three tag single click.

Comment: Hey Bindiya Patoliya, you copy-paste my answer in your edited comment!

Comment: No, i have not copied your ans, but when i am editing it at that time you have posting it, so